# Postgres: foreign key vs reference key?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, create-table

In **PostgreSQL**
is there any conceptual and/or performance difference between column-level foreign key and  table-level foreign key constraints
Which of the following table creation is better and why in PostgreSQL ?
If both of the are the same why not to make one of them to be deprecated?

```
    create table game
    (
    gdate date,
    htid int,
    vtid int,
    hscore int default 0,
    vscore int default 0,
    primary key (gdate, htid),
    foreign key (htid) references team,
    foreign key (vtid) references team
    );

create table game
(
    gdate date,
    htid int references team(tid),
    vtid int references team(tid),
    hscore int default 0,
    vscore int default 0,
    primary key (gdate, htid)
);
```

Thanks

Comment: Because the table level FK allows you build multiple column FK's e.g. `foreign key (some_fld, another_fld) references team(team_fld_1, team_fld_2)`

Comment: There is no technical difference, which one you prefer is a matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

A “table constraint” and a “column constraint” are two syntax options that produce the same result.  You can prove that by creating a table with either option and looking at the result with `\d` in `psql` or dumping the metadata with `pg_dump -s -t table_name dbname`.